# email send with celery doesn't arrive but the task executes, can you help me?

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery

I'm using **Python 3.5**, **Django 1.10**, **celery 3.1.18** and I'm developing on **Windows 8**

I'm following the book [Django by example](https://www.packtpub.com/web-development/django-example) and I finished chapter 7. I made an Online Shop where when you finish the Order the app must send an Email to the customer. The problem is that I'm using celery and rabbitmq also I installed flower to check all the tasks. The tasks execute correctly, but the Email never arrives.

Here's my tasks.py

```
from celery import task
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from .models import Pedido

@task
def pedido_creado(pedido_id):
    pedido = Pedido.objects.get(id=pedido_id)
    subject = 'Pedido nro. {}'.format(pedido.id)
    message = 'Querido {}, \n\nTu pedido fue exitosamente registrado. El id         de tu pedido es {}.'.format(pedido.nombre,pedido.id)
    mail_sent = send_mail(subject, message, 'admin@TiendaManualidades.com', [pedido.email], fail_silently=False,)
    return mail_sent
```

My views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import ItemPedido
from .forms import FormCreaPedido
from carro_compras.carro_compras import Carro
from .tasks import pedido_creado
def crear_pedido(request):
    carro = Carro(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FormCreaPedido(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        pedido = form.save()
        for item in carro:
            ItemPedido.objects.create(pedido=pedido, producto=item['producto'], precio=item['precio'], cantidad=item['cantidad'])
        carro.limpiar()
        pedido_creado.delay(pedido.id)
        return render(request, 'pedidos/pedido/creado.html', {'pedido':pedido})
    else:
        form = FormCreaPedido()
    return render(request, 'pedidos/pedido/crear.html', {'carro':carro, 'form':form})
```

My celery.py

```
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'TiendaManualidades.settings')

app = Celery('TiendaManualidades')

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

Finally you can see that the tasks are successful but the email didn't send

images
[images](http://razorluis.imgur.com/all/?third_party=1)

Comment: your images are not publicly available...

Comment: I'd guess your email is being refused by the receiver, in which case your task wouldn't possibly fail.